# mssql query issue date range

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

while running the following query in mssql 2k12,

```
select PROBSUMMARYM1.AFFECTED_ITEM,
sum(case when SLORESPONSEM1.BREACHED='t' then 1 else 0 end) BREACHED,
sum(case when SLORESPONSEM1.BREACHED='f' then 1 else 0 end) NOBREACHED,
SLORESPONSEM1.SLO_ID 
from PROBSUMMARYM1 
INNER JOIN SLORESPONSEM1 
ON NUMBER=FOREIGN_KEY 
where OPEN_TIME>'2014-11-12'
group by AFFECTED_ITEM,SLO_ID;
```

I get the desired output, however when I change the date in line 8 above to any one of following, I am only getting headers & no data, can anyone suggest what could be the issue, the db is having good amount of data for the mentioned date ranges, that is for sure and evident from some ready(boxed) reports from the application using same mssql instance

```
where OPEN_TIME<'2016-05-31'
```

or

```
where OPEN_TIME<'2016-01-01'
```

or

```
where OPEN_TIME between '2016-01-01' AND '2016-06-30'
```

Thanks and Regards
Hemant Vaswani

Comment: USE `CONVERT(DATE,OPEN_TIME,102)` in where clause

Comment: What is the data type of `OPEN_TIME`? Also, don't use `BETWEEN` for date range queries, and use `yyyymmdd` as opposed to `yyyy-mm-dd`. For reasons see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx,  https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx, and http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/.

Comment: data type of 'OPEN_TIME' is 'datetime'

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
select PROBSUMMARYM1.AFFECTED_ITEM,
sum(case when SLORESPONSEM1.BREACHED='t' then 1 else 0 end) BREACHED,
sum(case when SLORESPONSEM1.BREACHED='f' then 1 else 0 end) NOBREACHED,
SLORESPONSEM1.SLO_ID 
from PROBSUMMARYM1 
INNER JOIN SLORESPONSEM1 
ON NUMBER=FOREIGN_KEY 
where convert(date,OPEN_TIME) between '2014-11-12' And '2016-06-30'
group by AFFECTED_ITEM,SLO_ID;
```